# Oracle 12c error - Provider cannot be found. It may not be properly installed - occurring after uninstalling 64 bit and installing 32 bit

Tags: excel, oracle, oracle12c, ado, adodb

A user is getting an error while using a macro which connects to an Oracle DB via excel using ADO. They previously had Excel 2016 64 bit installed on their PC and Oracle 12c 64 bit installed as well. The macro worked flawlessly.

After having office 64 bit uninstalled and replaced with 32 bit, Oracle 12c 64 bit was uninstalled and Oracle 12c 32 bit was installed. Now excel cannot connect to the DB and we're seeing this error: "Provider cannot be found. It may not be properly installed".

Is it possible that additional files need to be deleted from the 64 bit installation?

Comment: Are you using the Instant Client or the full Oracle Client? Check your PATH environment variable to make sure it points to the 32-bit version of the client and remove the 64-bit client directory from PATH if it is no longer installed.

Comment: @pmdba I'm using the full Oracle Client. I checked the PATH environment variable and it's pointing to the 32-bit version. I'm at a loss here. Is there anything else that you can think of that I should check?